GE Stove "Burner On" and "Hot Cooktop" light are staying on
My GE flattop stove "Burner On" and "Hot Cooktop" light are staying on. I already tested the switches on each burner and they all test good. I tested for Ohms and Continuity. I unplugged it from the wall for about 30 minutes and plugged it back in. Not sure what to check next. It is an electric stove.

If an old stove I would say the switch part/section that turns on the light is shorted out/always on.  Newer stoves with electronics will be harder to find.  It should be fixed since you will get use to it being on when burner is off and won't notice that the burner is still on.  Not nice to test by hand if off or on.

I take it this is happening when the elements are stone cold?

Do the wires to the warning lights come from the controller switch for each burner or do they come from the burner? Assuming the former, from each burner switch in turn disconnect the wire to the Burner On light and see if the light goes out at any point. It may be more convenient to switch the breaker off and on rather than un-plug and plug-in the cord.

I would guess that the Burner On wires come from the controller switches but the Cooktop Hot connections come from the burners themselves. Probably in nomral operation as soon as any burner is turned ON both lights come on, and as soon as all burners are turned off then the burner on light turns off, but the cooktop hot light stays on until it cools.

With the power on you could probe the voltage at the burner on contact at each controller switch. With all switches OFF the voltage should be 0 V at these connections assuming this is a simple power connection and not some signal wire.

I have a GE electric cooktop that does this also, and a sharp bonk (sometimes my knuckle works, but it's easier with a pot or pan) to the area of the light turns it off. If you listen closely as you turn on a burner and the heat activates the "Hot Cooktop" light, mine has the click of a mechanical relay, which wear out over time. I think the relay is getting stuck in the "on" position and not able to move back to "off" automatically like it should.
As someone else suggested, you should definitely repair this, the lights are there as a safety measure and having the light always-on circumvents that safety measure. If a "bonk" shuts the light off, look for a mechanical relay in the vicinity and replace it. I'm not sure if this is a DIY replacement or if a service technician would have to do it.
Note: be careful with the "bonk" as the stovetop is glass. It doesn't take much force at all with a pan, with my knuckle I have to bonk it pretty hard but the knuckle's less likely to shatter glass.
